# Show that $\lambda(t)=\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}=-\frac{d}{dt} \log(S(t))$

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-writing, self-learning

> Let $T$ a continuous non-negative random variable that represents a failure time.
>   Taking $S(t)=P(T\geq t)$ and $f(t)$ the probability density function
>   of $T$. Show that
>   $$\lambda(t)=\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}=-\frac{d}{dt} \log S(t)$$ where
>   $\lambda(t)$ represents a failure rate.

I had some additional information
$$\lambda(t)=\frac{P(T\geq t)-P(T\geq t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t \, S(t)}$$
and

$$\lambda(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(t\leq T<t+\Delta t\mid T\leq t)}{\Delta t}$$

I tried to do some manipulation with that, but I can't get nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the distribution function of $T$ be $F(t)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$, whose density is $f(t)$. We then have the following:

\begin{align}
\lambda(t)&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{P(T\leq t+h)-P(T\leq t)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1-P(T> t+h)-P(T\leq t)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{P(T>t)-P(T> t+h)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&\stackrel{(a)}{=}\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{P(T\geq t)-P(T\geq t+h)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{S(t)-S(t+h)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&=-\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{S(t+h)-S(t)}{h}\right)\frac{1}{S(t)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{S(t)}\frac{d}{dt}S(t)=-\frac{d}{dt}\log(S(t)),
\end{align}
where $(a)$ above follows from the fact that $T$ is a continuous random variable, and hence $P(T> t)=P(T\geq t)$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$.